# EF Code First improving performance for self referencing, one to many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion, query-optimization

I have an `AccountGroup` which is a self-referencing entity. A leaf `AccountGroup` can contain 1 or more `Accounts`. Both entities have `Balance` property. Each `AccountGroup` has a `Balance` which is either a sum of `Balance`s in sub-groups or sum of `Balance`s of all Accounts (in case of leaf group).

In order to build a tree listing of all `AccountGroup`s and `Account`s I have to traverse this object graph recursively, which causes a lot (I mean a lot!!!) of calls to DB...

Is there any way to improve upon this in such way that # of DB calls is reduced?

Thanks

Here is the trimmed down code

### Account (belongs to only 1 AccountGroup)

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public string AccountType { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountGroup Group { get; set; }
}
```

### AccountGroup (has 0 or many AccountGroups, has 1 or more Accounts if it is a leaf)

```
public class AccountGroup
{
    public AccountGroup()
    {
        Accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
        Groups = new HashSet<AccountGroup>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsRoot { get { return Parent == null; } }
    public bool IsLeaf { get { return !Groups.Any(); } }
    public decimal Balance { get { return IsLeaf ? Accounts.Sum(a => a.Balance) : Groups.Sum(g => g.Balance); } } // if leaf group, get sum of all account balances, otherwise get sum of all subgroups
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Account> Accounts { get; private set; }
    public virtual ISet<AccountGroup> Groups { get; private set; }
    public virtual AccountGroup Parent { get; set; }
}
```

### Calling Code

```
// start processing root groups (ones without parent)
foreach (var rootGroup in db.AccountGroups.Include(g=>g.Groups).Where(g => g.ParentId == null))
{
    TraverseAccountGroup(rootGroup, 0);
}

// recursive method
private static void TraverseAccountGroup(AccountGroup accountGroup, int level)
{
    //
    // process account group
    //
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} ({2})", String.Empty.PadRight(level * 2, '.'), accountGroup.Name, level);
    //
    // if subgroups exist, process recursivelly
    //
    if (accountGroup.Groups.Any())
    {
        foreach (var subGroup in accountGroup.Groups)
        {
            TraverseAccountGroup(subGroup, level + 1);
        }
    }
    //
    // otherwise, process accounts belonging to leaf subgroup
    //
    else
    {
        foreach (var account in accountGroup.Accounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ACCOUNT [{0}]", account.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I always did this with database view containing CTE for hierarchical query.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka I have the CTE that does the job but EF code first does not support it (not yet in v5 anyway)...I could "step down" in my repository and use dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<> but I was hoping there may be a way to do this through ORM...

Comment: Yes code first is somehow limited in this but you can still "cheat" it and map the view in the same way as a table (if you don't want EF to generate DB for you - in such case it is more complex but still achievable). When it comes to performance problems it is usually time when you must leave architecture purity simply to make things work so `SqlQuery` is still a valid option.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka I agree with you, there may be no other choice...In case I create a view do I create a helper class (that is not my domain entity) and in it *somehow* attach/generate entities...Any help in this regards would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CTE Approach**

There are two ways to increase speed of queries against tree data types.  The first (and likely easiest) is using a Stored Procedure and the execute sql functionality of EF to load the tree.  The SProc will cache and the result set execution speed will be increased.  My recommendation for the query in the sproc would be a recursive CTE.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

```
with <CTEName> as
(
     SELECT
         <Root Query>
     FROM <TABLE>

     UNION ALL

     SELECT
         <Child Query>
     FROM <TABLE>
     INNER JOIN <CTEName>
         ON <CTEJoinCondition>
     WHERE 
          <TERMINATION CONDITION>

)
```

**Edit**

Execute your sproc or CTE inline with:

```
DbContext ctx = new SampleContext();
ctx.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>(@"SQL OR SPROC COMMAND HERE", new[] { "Param1", "Param2", "Etc" });
```

**Flatten Your Tree Structure**

The second approach is to build a flat representation of your tree.  You can flatten a tree into a flat structure for quick querying and then use a linkage between the flat structure and the actual tree node to cut out the self referencing entity.  You can build the flat structure using the above recursive CTE query.

This is just one approach but there are many papers on the subject:

http://www.governor.co.uk/news-plus-views/2010/5/17/depth-first-tree-flattening-with-the-yield-keyword-in-c-sharp/

**EDIT: Adding additional clarification**
Just a note, the Recursive CTE cache's the symbols for the query before iterating over the structure.  This is the fastest and simplest way to write a query to solve your problem.  However, this HAS to be a SQL query.  You can use execute sql directly or you can execute a SProc.  Sprocs cache the execution graph after being ran so they perform better than native queries that have to build an execution plan prior to running.  This is entirely up to you.

The issue with a flat representation of your tree is you have to routinely rebuild or constantly upkeep the flat structure.  Depending on your query path would determine what flattening algorithm you should use, but the end result remains the same.  The flat structure is the only way to "accomplish" what you want to do inside EF without having to cheat and execute raw SQL through the DBConnection.

Comment: I'd preferr CTE but as per my comment to @Ladislav Mrnka, after I create sproc with CTE how do I integrate it with other domain entities? Do I create a brand new domain entity and manage it on sql level or do I create helper class that maps 1:1 to cte results and then at my repository level I use it to build/attach domain entities? Is there an example of this?

Comment: Also, In the example for flattening tree, would that generate multiple queries also? I agree that it is better than recursion method I have, but yield or no yield I am thinking loop will cause multiple queries...No?

Comment: Flattening the tree should be able to execute with 1 round trip to the database.  You would load the additional views using _context.Set<FlatTree>().Include(x => x.ActualTreeNode).Include(x => x.OtherObjectRefFromHere)

Comment: As for binding directly to an object set:

DbContext ctx = new SampleContext();
            ctx.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>(@"SQL OR SPROC COMMAND HERE", new[] { "Param1", "Param2", "Etc" });

You can then use .Include(...) to lower your lazy loading round trips.  That command will load the type and also wire the bindings to the fluent configuration you have set.