# How can I recursively Include ALL navigable properties to emulate Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

To emulate Lazy Loading, I would like to have a method that recursively Include's the complete object graph via Eager Loading so that upon loading the entity, all of its related data is loaded as well.

From MSDN documentation:

- To include a single reference: query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference).
- To include a single collection: query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection).
- To include a reference and then a reference one level down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference.Level2Reference).
- To include a reference and then a collection one level down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference.Level2Collection).
- To include a collection and then a reference one level down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference)).
- To include a collection and then a collection one level down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection)).
- To include a collection and then a reference one level down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference)).
- To include a collection and then a collection one level down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection)).
- To include a collection, a reference, and a reference two levels down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference.Level3Reference)).
- To include a collection, a collection, and a reference two levels down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection.Select(l2 => l2.Level3Reference))).

Question:

How can I recursively Include ALL navigable properties and build this into a generic repository method so that I can get a deep object graph of an entity whenever required, regardless if new properties were added?

Comment: You probably don't want to do this. The number of Includes in a query is recommended not to be more than three. Especially when Includes cause star queries the result set quickly explodes into unmanageable proportions.

Comment: Not possible with LINQ (to Entities). The only way I've heard about is a Stored Procedure with SQL Common Table Expression (CTE): http://stackoverflow.com/a/11621006/270591

Comment: This will be a one-off method, so I'm not worried about performance, I'm just trying to ensure that I get a FULL entity graph (as if Lazy Loading was enabled) and as it stands now, I am achieving this functionality by manually including all the navigable properties, but when the model changes, I must go update my GetFullEntity method, which is what I'm trying to address with this question.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is an edited version that should meet your requirements a little better:

```
private static void EnumerateAllIncludesList(DbContext context, IEnumerable entities, List<object> entitiesLoaded = null)
{
    if (entitiesLoaded == null)
        entitiesLoaded = new List<object>();

    foreach (var entity in entities)
        EnumerateAllIncludesEntity(context, entity, entitiesLoaded);

}

private static void EnumerateAllIncludesEntity(DbContext context, object entity, List<object> entitiesLoaded)
{
    if (entitiesLoaded.Contains(entity))
        return;

    entitiesLoaded.Add(entity);

    Type type = entity.GetType();
    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
    {
        var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

        bool isCollection = propertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(IEnumerable)) &&
                            !propertyType.Equals(typeof(string));

        if (isCollection)
        {
            var entry = context.Entry(entity);

            if(entry.Member(propertyInfo.Name) as DbCollectionEntry == null)
                continue;

            entry.Collection(propertyInfo.Name).Load();

            var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(entity);

            if (propertyValue == null)
                continue;

            EnumerateAllIncludesList(context, (IEnumerable)propertyValue, entitiesLoaded);
        }
        else if ((!propertyType.IsValueType && !propertyType.Equals(typeof(string))))
        {
            var entry = context.Entry(entity);

            if (entry.Member(propertyInfo.Name) as DbReferenceEntry == null)
                continue;

            entry.Reference(propertyInfo.Name).Load();

            var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(entity);

            if (propertyValue == null)
                continue;

            EnumerateAllIncludesEntity(context, propertyValue, entitiesLoaded);
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

You would use this like so:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var result = context.People.Where(x => x.Id == 1).ToList();
    EnumerateAllIncludesList(context,result);
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in your answer, this will not work if any navigation properties have a corresponding inverse property. Suppose you have an Employee entity with a reference property to the Manager, which has a navigation property Employees. You'd end up trying to create `employees.Include("Manager").Include("Manager.Employees").Include("Manager.Employees.Manager").Include("Manager.Employees.Manager.Emplyees").<...>`

Comment: I did miss something: you're not looking at the collection element's properties, so that specific example wouldn't fail in the way I described, but if `employee.Manager` is again an employee, you'd still get `.Include("Manager").Include("Manager.Manager").Include<...>`

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I am having with this code.  I have sub entities that link back to parent entities, and this code causes an endless loop as @hvd has pointed out.  Can we somehow track to ensure we stop recurring if we are in an endless loop?

Comment: Okay, I've amended the answer to cater better for the scenario with circular references. This will execute multiple queries though - there is no way around that.

Comment: **The property 'TimeStamp' on type 'People' is not a navigation property. The Reference and Collection methods can only be used with navigation properties. Use the Property or ComplexProperty method.**  Also, with your example, you make a list first?  Is this necessary?  I returned a result[0] after the EnumerateAllIncludesList(context,result); but I'm not sure how that entity gets updated as I was thinking we needed an 'out' on the result so that we get something new back out.

Comment: I know this is very late on, but I've added an amend to the code above that should address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use model-first or database-first, you could write some T4 template to generate what you need using edmx model. It is not easy, but possible.