# Exception for disposed DataContext even with ToList() applied

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'm in the classic old situation - trying to return a set of elements that I query via Linq to SQL, but that are dependent on the DataContext in which they were queried.

Pretty much every example I've seen just adds ToList(), which I've done, but it didn't solve it.  I thought the ToList() call would force evaluation of the query, but it doesn't seem to.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<WebService.Score> GetTopNScores(string gameName, int count)
    {
        using (var dc = new WebService.MyDataContext())
        {
            var q = from row in dc.GetTable<WebService.Score>()
                    where row.GameName == gameName
                    orderby row.ScoreValue descending
                    select row;

            return q.Take(count).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I'd like to avoid DataLoadOptions and having to specify the dependency for each column, because the database format is still evolving and I'd need to update the code for every change.

Any idea why the ToList() call is not forcing the evaluation of the data?  And what solution I can attempt?

Comment: I suspect the error is elsewhere. Forcing immediate evaluation is exactly what `.ToList()` is supposed to do. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: What is the exception exactly?

Comment: If you access a complex type property from `WebService.Score` somewhere later on that might give this exception.

Comment: *I'd like to avoid DataLoadOptions* Well, clearly you can't. You're triggering lazy loading outside the scope of the context.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558334/how-can-i-recursively-include-all-navigable-properties-to-emulate-lazy-loading/15573086#15573086, it uses reflection to get all you Collection type fields and manually load them

Comment: Way too complicated and error prone for selecting rows out of a table.  I decided in my case I didn't want to expose the data structure from the middle tier anyway, so I wound up doing "select new" and creating a simpler structure that I pass back to the caller with just the fields I want.  It's a a better approach for me, but doesn't solve the underlying problem.